# How can a PHP script detect if it has been invoked as a script or from the shell?

Tags: php, shell, scripting, invoke

I have a PHP script on a webserver.

This file is invoked via the shell by another program **but** it could still be run by the webserver in response to an HTTP request.

How can the script determine the way it was invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways; I check if `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is empty. I think the technically correct way is to see if `php_sapi_name()` returns `cli`

Comment: Ya, that's probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

If it is executed from the shell then it won't have HTTP headers because it wasn't requested from HTTP protocols.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain environmental variables you can check. for example [$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]))
   // run by server
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I write a lot of applications that run concurrently in the shell and web contexts,
and this one liner makes it easy

```
function isWEB()
         {
         return $GLOBALS['argc']===NULL;
         }
```