# Is there a way to test whether a Python function or method has been invoked directly from a shell?

Tags: python, invoke

Adding to the list for [rake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7201205/656912) and [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2671649/656912): Is there a way to test whether a Python function or method has been invoked directly from a Python shell, as opposed to being invoked from within a `.py` script file?

For example I want to define an expression, `test_expr` that behaves as follows when the expression appears in a module "shelltest.py",

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""Module shelltest.py"""

def test_expr():
    #...
```

Case (1): it yields `True` when invoked directly from a shell

```
>>> import shelltest
>>> shelltest.test_expr()
True
```

Case (2): it yields `False` when imported into another module, "other.py" and used in code there

```
#!/usr/bin/python
"""Module other.py"""

import shelltest

def other_func():
    # ...
    shelltest.test_expr()
```

which is in turn invoked from a shell

```
>>> import other
>>> other.other_func()
False
```

Comment: Can you clarify if you are talking about running stuff in the interactive shell vs from a file, or talking about running something vs an `import`?

Comment: Generally, in Python, you can introspect everything, and find out all sorts of things. But whatever you would do differently in your function based on this information, you probably shouldn't do it. It would make the function magical and therefore surprising and confusing.

Comment: Perhaps if you detailed what you would do with the information, we can help find a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  This would be difficult to implement, and confusing for your users.  Can you explain why you want this and what you'll do with it?  There might be a better way.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: This is so I can confuse users by changing where error reports are directed. I would like to avoid raising an exception and just print an error message directly for certain functions invoked directly from a shell prompt.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: this is a bad idea.  Exceptions are a real part of the Python eco-system, and trying to hide them through magic like this will only make things difficult.  Do the simple thing instead: let the errors print as they already do.  If you don't like the way the interactive prompt displays errors, look into `sys.excepthook`.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: You'll need to explain the use case in which this will "make things difficult". Mine is quite simple: There's a particular kind of error that users can have an opportunity to recover from. In the shell case, it makes sense for my code to provide a message and some opportunities to make that recovery directly (the shell is the UI); in the imported-and-used-in-code case, an exception, handled by the calling code is what makes the most sense (the coder of the using code is providing the "UI").

Comment: @NedBatchelder: In effect, I'm providing a "default" UI for the case where the function is called "naked", and letting the caller provide whatever UI he deems appropriate in the case where the function is incorporated into some other code.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: why not just provide two functions, the "raw" one and the "nice" one then?  As you are planning to do it, imagine this scenario: I intend to write a program to call your function.  To get a feel for how it works, I try it out in the interactive interpreter.  Then I write my program, and it works differently! Bizarre!  If you want two different behaviors, then provide two different functions, or at least, optional arguments to one function.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: Good point, but we can discuss that on ux.SE. Here I'm just looking for an answer to my question.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: I hate answers of the form, "You should never ever do that, but when you do, do it like this..."

Comment: @NedBatchelder: So do I; the second clause alone is preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are at the shell, then `__name__ == '__main__'`. (In addition, as Ned Batchelder notes, this will only tell you where the function was defined.)

You probably don't want to test this inside a function - it's used instead to distinguish whether a module is being called as a main programme or not. Your functions should probably work the same way regardless, and if you need different functions, you should import a different module containing the same function names.

Do something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   import formain as bumpf
else:
   import forscripts as bumpf

bumpf.domagic()
```

As to determining whether you're in a web environment - do that in code that will only be called from the web. Python scripts are typically not invoked by CGI, so this doesn't really arise as a use case.

Comment: This would only help you figure out if the function were defined in the shell or a file, no?  It doesn't give you a clue to how it was invoked.

Comment: That's not true. http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts says that `__name__` is set to `__main__` when the module is executed as a script.

Comment: @Colselaw How does that contradict what I said?

Comment: Because what you said was "This would only help you figure out if the function were defined in the shell or a file, no? It doesn't give you a clue to how it was invoked." But testing for `__name__ == "__main__"` is how you determine whether a module was invoked from the shell or from another module. (Loading it from the REPL gives a `__name__` of the module from which it was loaded, though).

Comment: @Colselaw Again, how does that contradict what I said?

Comment: What you said is that "it doesn't give you a clue how it was invoked". But it **does** give you a clue how it was invoked. If the `__name__` is `__main__`, then it was invoked directly from the shell. If the `__name__` is not `__main__`, then it was invoked by being loaded as a module. I would say that's a pretty good "clue how it was invoked".

Comment: @Colselaw Do you understand that there is a distinction between a function and a module?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python
    """Module shelltest.py"""
    
    def test_expr():
      if __name__ == "__main__":
        return True
      else:
        return __name__
    
    print test_expr()

If I execute this from the shell, it prints `True`. When I load it as a module then execute the function, the function states its module's name - this is exactly what you're asking for, yes?

Comment: @Colselaw The point I am making is that your criticism does not make sense, because the question and answer are directed to the execution of functions, not the loading of modules.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import sys
>>> called_via_shell = lambda: sys.stdin.isatty()
>>> called_via_shell()
True
```

More information and code exsamples are here:
http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/userinterfaces.html#AEN795

Comment: Might as well just be:  `called_via_shell = sys.stdin.isatty`

Comment: This gives True if executed as part of a `.py` script too, so it doesn't distinguish the cases I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way to check for this is to check for `sys.ps1`.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print sys.ps1
'>>> '
$ cat > script.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
print sys.ps1
$ python script.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 3, in <module>
    print sys.ps1
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ps1'
```

I think the other answers are wrong, because `__name__` is `__main__` in scripts and in the interactive shell.

Comment: This is better than the `__main__` answers, but doesn't directly address whether the function is invoked from the shell or a file.  It will accurately indicate whether the program as a whole is running in the shell or from a file.

Comment: Ned, the function can check for `sys.ps1` too. Should I edit my answer to include that?

Comment: to be honest, I don't exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score -1):

If this **module** was executed from the shell, `__name__` will be set to `__main__`. Otherwise, it will be set to the name of the calling module.  You'll see this idiom in modules all the time:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # do something with the library
```